# Ubuntu box crashes

Tags: 11.04

I have a Ubuntu 11.04 box running 24/7. It started to crash any couple of days recently.
I checked in kern.log, dmesg... but did not find anything there. N Is there a specific place where shutdown reason (temperature, or whatever) are logged ?

Answer (score 3):

I would start with checking out `/var/log/syslog`. It's a catch all for syslog messages.

Comment: This question is asking *where* to look for information, so this really does answer the question. This is an answer, not a comment.